# Connecting RDS instance via mysqlworkbench failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created RDS instance with my own VPC. I had selected public accessible while creating the RDS instance. I have attached internet gateway with VPC. The security group for RDS has entry for 3306 port with my system IP address. I am using default ACL. Still on connecting the RDS instance from mysqlworkench error is coming.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Double check that you have added to correct information and test connection from above
>   image. You also need to open 3306 port for your instance.  Check if
>   you have root user privileges in console.

[image: Connecting to RDS instance]

Comment: How to check root user privilege in console?

Comment: While creating AWS RDS you have asked to enter master username and password with help of those credentials you should connect easily to your database.